# pdf2image not working with gunicorn/flask

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn, poppler

For the past day I have been trying to incorporate pdf2image into my flask webservice.
The problem is, whatever I do, I still get the "Is poppler installed and in PATH?" error message.
I have written a little program that just prints the number of pages in a pdf file. This works completely fine, inside and outside the venv containing flask. If I try to do this from the flask file, I get the error. I even tried calling the very same function in the test code, but to no avail. I don't really know what to do anymore, so any help is greatly appreciated.

P.S.: I don't really know what source to include for this post, so just feel free to ask and I will provide it.

Comment: I have the same issue (pdf2image working locally with Flask, also working from command-line python3 on the server, but failing with the 'PATH' message under gunicorn/flask). Will look into it within hours... If you could fix it, please write an answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the symptoms which you describe. For me the problem was the following:

in the .service file used by systemd to start gunicorn, I had an incomplete path variable. The solution was to add the path to pdftoppm and pdftocairo, which in my case (on Debian 10) was /usr/bin
The solution is therefore that the .service file includes

```
[Service]
...
Environment="PATH=<your_app_path>/venv/bin:/usr/bin"
```

Note: This problem and its solution are thus broader than a pdf2image issue, but it seems to show up frequently with pdf2image... assuming this is true, I hope that your question and my response are both relevant.

Comment: That should do it. I solved it by doing 
`if '/usr/bin' not in os.environ:
            os.environ['PATH'] = '/usr/bin'`

Both versions should work.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my response and confirming that you had a similar working solution. However, I am surprised: `os.environ['PATH'] = '/usr/bin' `does not appear to supplement the PATH variable with the missing path, but rather replace it entirely. If you had anything useful in your path variable other than /usr/bin, I suspect that this could cause problems. It will work if, at the point you want to access poppler, you don't need things outside /usr/bin, otherwise, that could replace a problem with another one.

Comment: Thanks... looking for this for a long time